# If $f$ is an integrable function, g is a simple function, and $|f(x)|\geq |g(x)|$, then $g$ is integrable, proof verification

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, solution-verification

Want to prove that if $f$ is an integrable function, g is a simple function, and $|f(x)|\geq |g(x)|$, then $g$ is integrable.

My attempt: For simple function $g=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \chi_{E_i}$ to be integrable we must, per definition, have that $\mu(E_i)<\infty$ for all $i$ for which $\alpha_i \neq 0$, where $\chi$ is the characteristic function and $E_i$ is a measurable set.

It can be shown that $f$ is integrable if and only if $|f|$ is integrable, which implies that

$\int |f(x)|d\mu<\infty$.

Now by assumption

$\int |\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \chi_{E_i}|d\mu = \int |g(x)|d\mu \leq \int |f(x)|d\mu<\infty$

and since we have that

$\int |\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \chi_{E_i}|d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^n |\alpha_i| \int \chi_{E_i}d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^n |\alpha_i| \mu(E_i)$,

it follows that $\mu(E_i)<\infty$. Is this a valid proof? I'm a bit concerned whether $\int |g(x)|d\mu \leq \int |f(x)|d\mu$ makes sense considering the integral symbol $\int$ is used when $g(x)$ is an integrable fucntion, which is what we want to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct. Also, the symbol $\say{\int}$ makes sense for any positive measurable function.

Another way of seeing that is by remembering the definition of the integral of a positive, measurable function (in our case $|f|$), as the supremum of the integral over all simple functions below of that function. Now also observe that we can write any simple function $s(x)= \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \chi_{A_i}$ as $\sum_{j=1}^{m} b_j \chi_{B_j}$, where now $B_i \cap B_j =\emptyset$, for $i\neq j$. This representation gives us that $|s(x)|=\sum_{j=1}^{m} |b_j| \chi_{B_j}$, i.e. it is also a simple (and now positive) function. In particular for $g$, ee have that $|g|$ is a simple function, below $f$.

Therefore by the definition of $\int|f|$ as the supremum mentioned above, we have the result.